# MySQL user denied

Tags: mysql, windows-10, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1064

I'm trying to connect to my Server I bought DataBases and I can't log in to server because it says 
"access denied for user" 
I managed to configure my localhost server and did a root password trough installer.
what should I do next? I verified 10 times already the Login, username, password I got from the site I bought it.

** I don't have any Skills/Experience in Coding/Server stuff ** sry.
the error I get

[image]

Comment: Did you set up a user specifically for the machine you're connecting from? In mysql, each login from a different machine is treated as an individual user

Comment: You say localhost but your redacted screenshot displays something like `45.` and `bzq-1`... I suspect it's just what the error message says: you haven't granted permission for the appropriate host.

Comment: This looks like some sort of login to a Counter-Strike database. Are you using the correct port number, 27015? I don't know anything about Counter-Strike, I just know this is one of the ports used.